# How to link a separate storyboard to each particular tab in uitabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app which has 5 major user flows..each flow is a few screens linking to each other...so each flow warranties its own storyboard. Each storyboard starts with a custom view controller that is embedded in a navigation controller. So far so good.

Now all of this is "stitched" together via a UITabBarController. This is the most default UI design ever known to iOS.

But turns out I don't really know how to link from tabbarcontroller, which is in its own storyboard (that is set as the main one on code project) to any of the other storyboards.

This problem looks so! simple, so I think I am missing something utterly obvious, but I just can't figure out how to do it.

So how do I link from tab bar controller in storyboard 1 to the initial view controller in storyboard 2 when a tab is tapped?

Comment: 1) Why do you need independent storyboards?  You should be able to accomplish this with a single storyboard.  2) However, since you already have it set up this way, I don't know of anyway to link one storyboard to another via IB.  I would do it programmatically and subclass your tabbarcontroller and instantiate its controllers with the initial view controller of each storyboard.

Comment: The difference is subtle but I am actually not asking what you paraphrased. I need to link specifically from UITabBarrController to a VC from different storyboard...if it would be any other controller type, i have the solution and it;s very easy. But this one is about UITabbarController that sits in a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in code. You can have the tab bar controller (tbc for short) and the controller in the first tab in the app's main storyboard, and in the app delegate, instantiate the other controllers using `instantiateInitialViewController`. Create a mutable array by copying the tbc's viewController array, add the other controllers you instantiated to it, and then set that array as the tbc's `viewControllers` array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your viewcontroller programmatically in tabbar.